# Inserting into CollectionFS in input change event causes refresh and error

Tags: javascript, meteor, upload, filesystems

After much tinkering with a problem, I decided to move file upload to `change` event in the file input as it's the most common method I see online.

HTML:

```
    <form class="form-inline" id="cost-estimate-form">
        <div class="form-field-short col s12 m6">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">insert_photo</i>
            <label for="input-file">Upload photos</label>
            <input id="input-file" type="file" name="images" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf" multiple/> <!-- todo: ugly on safari -->
        </div>
        <!-- Rest of code -->
```

.js:

```
'change #input-file': function(event, template) {
    uploadedImageFiles = [];
    FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
        Image.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
            //If !err, we have inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and
            //kicked off the data upload using HTTP
        });
    });
},
```

Now, whenever I select three files for the input in the browser I get this error in the browser console log:

```
cfs_power-queue.js:525 Error: "Queue" network [undefined], Error
    at cfs_upload-http.js:382
    at cfs_upload-http.js:108
    at underscore.js:794
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (cfs_upload-http.js:167)
PowerQueue.runTaskDone @ cfs_power-queue.js:525
taskCallbackDone @ cfs_power-queue.js:607
(anonymous) @ cfs_upload-http.js:382
(anonymous) @ cfs_upload-http.js:108
(anonymous) @ underscore.js:794
xhr.onreadystatechange @ cfs_upload-http.js:167
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
httpCall @ cfs_upload-http.js:237
gotBinaryCallback @ cfs_upload-http.js:373
reader.onload @ cfs_data-man.js:336
FileReader (async)
read @ cfs_data-man.js:341
(anonymous) @ cfs_data-man.js:363
dataManGetBlob @ cfs_data-man.js:289
dataManGetBinary @ cfs_data-man.js:344
_taskHandler @ cfs_upload-http.js:366
PowerQueue.runTask @ cfs_power-queue.js:606
PowerQueue.updateThrottleUp @ cfs_power-queue.js:412
PowerQueue.next @ cfs_power-queue.js:461
(anonymous) @ cfs_power-queue.js:575
withValue @ meteor.js:1077
(anonymous) @ meteor.js:464
(anonymous) @ meteor.js:1105
setTimeout (async)
setTimeout @ meteor.js:487
PowerQueue.runTaskDone @ cfs_power-queue.js:574
taskCallbackDone @ cfs_power-queue.js:607
(anonymous) @ cfs_upload-http.js:384
(anonymous) @ cfs_upload-http.js:108
(anonymous) @ underscore.js:794
xhr.onreadystatechange @ cfs_upload-http.js:231
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
httpCall @ cfs_upload-http.js:237
gotBinaryCallback @ cfs_upload-http.js:373
reader.onload @ cfs_data-man.js:336
FileReader (async)
read @ cfs_data-man.js:341
(anonymous) @ cfs_data-man.js:363
dataManGetBlob @ cfs_data-man.js:289
dataManGetBinary @ cfs_data-man.js:344
_taskHandler @ cfs_upload-http.js:366
PowerQueue.runTask @ cfs_power-queue.js:606
PowerQueue.updateThrottleUp @ cfs_power-queue.js:412
PowerQueue.next @ cfs_power-queue.js:461
PowerQueue.run @ cfs_power-queue.js:750
PowerQueue.queueTaskHandler @ cfs_power-queue.js:638
PowerQueue.runTask @ cfs_power-queue.js:597
PowerQueue.updateThrottleUp @ cfs_power-queue.js:412
PowerQueue.next @ cfs_power-queue.js:461
(anonymous) @ cfs_power-queue.js:575
withValue @ meteor.js:1077
(anonymous) @ meteor.js:464
(anonymous) @ meteor.js:1105
setTimeout (async)
setTimeout @ meteor.js:487
PowerQueue.runTaskDone @ cfs_power-queue.js:574
subQueueCallbackDone @ cfs_power-queue.js:598
subQueue.onRelease @ cfs_power-queue.js:631
PowerQueue.next @ cfs_power-queue.js:474
(anonymous) @ cfs_power-queue.js:575
withValue @ meteor.js:1077
(anonymous) @ meteor.js:464
(anonymous) @ meteor.js:1105
setTimeout (async)
setTimeout @ meteor.js:487
PowerQueue.runTaskDone @ cfs_power-queue.js:574
taskCallbackDone @ cfs_power-queue.js:607
(anonymous) @ cfs_upload-http.js:384
(anonymous) @ cfs_upload-http.js:108
(anonymous) @ underscore.js:794
xhr.onreadystatechange @ cfs_upload-http.js:231
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
httpCall @ cfs_upload-http.js:237
gotBinaryCallback @ cfs_upload-http.js:373
reader.onload @ cfs_data-man.js:336
FileReader (async)
read @ cfs_data-man.js:341
(anonymous) @ cfs_data-man.js:363
dataManGetBlob @ cfs_data-man.js:289
dataManGetBinary @ cfs_data-man.js:344
_taskHandler @ cfs_upload-http.js:366
PowerQueue.runTask @ cfs_power-queue.js:606
PowerQueue.updateThrottleUp @ cfs_power-queue.js:412
PowerQueue.next @ cfs_power-queue.js:461
(anonymous) @ cfs_power-queue.js:575
withValue @ meteor.js:1077
(anonymous) @ meteor.js:464
(anonymous) @ meteor.js:1105
setTimeout (async)
setTimeout @ meteor.js:487
PowerQueue.runTaskDone @ cfs_power-queue.js:574
taskCallbackDone @ cfs_power-queue.js:607
(anonymous) @ cfs_upload-http.js:384
(anonymous) @ cfs_upload-http.js:108
(anonymous) @ underscore.js:794
xhr.onreadystatechange @ cfs_upload-http.js:231
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
httpCall @ cfs_upload-http.js:237
gotBinaryCallback @ cfs_upload-http.js:373
reader.onload @ cfs_data-man.js:336
FileReader (async)
read @ cfs_data-man.js:341
(anonymous) @ cfs_data-man.js:363
dataManGetBlob @ cfs_data-man.js:289
dataManGetBinary @ cfs_data-man.js:344
_taskHandler @ cfs_upload-http.js:366
PowerQueue.runTask @ cfs_power-queue.js:606
PowerQueue.updateThrottleUp @ cfs_power-queue.js:412
PowerQueue.next @ cfs_power-queue.js:461
(anonymous) @ cfs_power-queue.js:575
withValue @ meteor.js:1077
(anonymous) @ meteor.js:464
(anonymous) @ meteor.js:1105
setTimeout (async)
setTimeout @ meteor.js:487
PowerQueue.runTaskDone @ cfs_power-queue.js:574
taskCallbackDone @ cfs_power-queue.js:607
(anonymous) @ cfs_upload-http.js:384
(anonymous) @ cfs_upload-http.js:108
(anonymous) @ underscore.js:794
xhr.onreadystatechange @ cfs_upload-http.js:231
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
httpCall @ cfs_upload-http.js:237
gotBinaryCallback @ cfs_upload-http.js:373
reader.onload @ cfs_data-man.js:336
FileReader (async)
read @ cfs_data-man.js:341
(anonymous) @ cfs_data-man.js:363
dataManGetBlob @ cfs_data-man.js:289
dataManGetBinary @ cfs_data-man.js:344
_taskHandler @ cfs_upload-http.js:366
PowerQueue.runTask @ cfs_power-queue.js:606
PowerQueue.updateThrottleUp @ cfs_power-queue.js:412
PowerQueue.next @ cfs_power-queue.js:461
PowerQueue.run @ cfs_power-queue.js:750
PowerQueue.queueTaskHandler @ cfs_power-queue.js:638
PowerQueue.runTask @ cfs_power-queue.js:597
PowerQueue.updateThrottleUp @ cfs_power-queue.js:412
PowerQueue.next @ cfs_power-queue.js:461
PowerQueue._autoStartTasks @ cfs_power-queue.js:366
PowerQueue.add @ cfs_power-queue.js:391
UploadTransferQueue.self.uploadFile @ cfs_upload-http.js:578
beginStorage @ cfs_collection.js:246
(anonymous) @ cfs_collection.js:282
(anonymous) @ mongo.js:720
(anonymous) @ meteor.js:1105
_maybeInvokeCallback @ ddp-client.js:3679
dataVisible @ ddp-client.js:3709
(anonymous) @ ddp-client.js:4560
_.each._.forEach @ underscore.js:149
_runAfterUpdateCallbacks @ ddp-client.js:4559
_performWrites @ ddp-client.js:4549
_flushBufferedWrites @ ddp-client.js:4512
_livedata_data @ ddp-client.js:4478
onMessage @ ddp-client.js:3526
(anonymous) @ ddp-client.js:2909
_.each._.forEach @ underscore.js:149
self.socket.onmessage @ ddp-client.js:2908
REventTarget.dispatchEvent @ ddp-client.js:143
SockJS._dispatchMessage @ ddp-client.js:1310
SockJS._didMessage @ ddp-client.js:1376
that.ws.onmessage @ ddp-client.js:1532

(2) Navigated to http://localhost:3000/travel/travel_requests/new
```

So, error. Then refresh page (Navigation) twice.

And the input loses the selection obviously.

And if I run `db.cfs.images.filerecord.find({}).pretty()` in the db, I get this:

```
{
    "_id" : "rEeTyZNiXKokabskw",
    "original" : {
        "name" : "IMG_3867.JPG",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-19T02:57:55Z"),
        "size" : 4231984,
        "type" : "image/jpeg"
    },
    "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-15T07:31:44.011Z"),
    "copies" : {
        "images" : {
            "name" : "IMG_3867.JPG",
            "type" : "image/jpeg",
            "size" : 4231984,
            "key" : "images-rEeTyZNiXKokabskw-IMG_3867.JPG",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-15T07:31:44Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-15T07:31:44Z")
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "csmJXhToHqpQ3PTo3",
    "original" : {
        "name" : "IMG_3868.JPG",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-19T02:58:07Z"),
        "size" : 4103858,
        "type" : "image/jpeg"
    },
    "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-15T07:31:46.481Z"),
    "copies" : {
        "images" : {
            "name" : "IMG_3868.JPG",
            "type" : "image/jpeg",
            "size" : 4103858,
            "key" : "images-csmJXhToHqpQ3PTo3-IMG_3868.JPG",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-15T07:31:46Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-15T07:31:46Z")
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "zypefr68MXpeBp3uY",
    "original" : {
        "name" : "IMG_3869.JPG",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-19T02:58:10Z"),
        "size" : 4108047,
        "type" : "image/jpeg"
    },
    "chunkSize" : 2097152,
    "chunkCount" : 0,
    "chunkSum" : 2
}
```

So, two files are completely uploaded and one is not.

My router for the template is like so:

```
Router.route('travel_request', {
    path: '/travel/travel_requests/new',
    yieldTemplates: {
        'travel_request': {to: 'body'}
    },
    data: function(){
        return {
            userId: Meteor.userId(),
            createdAt: new Date(),
            mdApproval: 0,
            mApprovalDate: null,
            mdRejectReason: "",
            aoApproval: 0,
            aoApprovalDate: null,
            aoRejectReason: "",
            travelCostEstimates: {localTransportFare: 0, airFare: 0, hotelFare: 0, overseasFare: 0, businessExpenses: 0, miscFare:0, totalFare: 0},
            travelRequestRows: [],
            images: [],
        };
    },
    /*
    onBeforeAction: function(){
        if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'admin')){
            sweetAlert('Admin cannot log Travel Requests.');
            Router.go('home');
        } else {
            this.next();
        }
    },
    */
    subscriptions: function(){
        Meteor.subscribe('users');
        // this.subscribe('travel.images').wait();
    },
    action: SignedIn
});
```

The `Image` collection is defined like so:

```
Image = new FS.Collection("images", {
    /* the file director: .meteor/local/uploads */
    stores:[new FS.Store.FileSystem("images",{path:Meteor.settings.uploadRoot+"/uploads"})],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*', 'application/pdf'] //allow only images and pdf in this FS.Collection
        }
    }
});

if(Meteor.isServer){
    Image.allow({
        'insert': function () {
            // add custom authentication code here
            return true;
        },
        'update': function () {
            return true;
        },
        'download':function(){
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Meteor version is `Meteor 1.4.3.2`.

Any help in figuring out what the error is and why the client refreshes and how to fix these problems is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try proposed methods from here: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up-legacy/issues/150 ?

Comment: @Styx: Yes I did, no help though

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are storing the uploaded files in the file system, and meteor will rebuild and restart when it detects the new files. This explains your erratic results.

This question describes a similar problem: [Image Upload using fs.writeFile() shows corrupt Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906248/image-upload-using-fs-writefile-shows-corrupt-images/44909857#44909857)

You need to avoid accessing the file system completely, which is unfortunate, but you'll just need to work out how to do it

Comment: Or just store files outside of meteor project folder.

Comment: You should treat the file system as being out of bounds. If you are running in a docker container the file system is ready only, so you can't do it. If it's outside the meteor hierarchy you can't serve up those files anyway. Use a service like S3 or filestack